# gulp error: vfs.watch is not a function

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have this gulpfile in my office and its working perfectly.
but when i try to use it at home i get this error and i don't know what is wrong with it. 
I tried to install all the packages in the dependency and resolve all the error but I cant fix this one:

[image]

and here is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./"
    });

    gulp.watch("css/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('css/partials/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("css/*.css").on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("js/*.js").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {

    gulp.src('css/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function(f) {
            return f.base;
        }));

    gulp.src('css/partials/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function(f) {
            return f.base;
        }));

});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.watch('css/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('css/partials/*.scss', ['sass']);

});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to recently update node and npm?

Since watch is not recognized as a function at all you can't get vfs to look at your local file system.

You could always try using this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-vfs

Comment: yes, i did updated my node ! is it going to be ok if i install gulp-vfs ?

Comment: Yeah I ran into a similar situation with the update and just installing gulp-vfs allows the vfs to localize to the project and gulp-vfs acts as sort of a middleman. You should just have to install it and then run your default task and be off an running again.

Comment: Oh and yes it will be okay. I would just ensure you place it in your package json file. So not only would you npm install gulp-vfs you might also want to npm install --save gulp-vfs. Since you're switching from environment to environment. That's why often times you want to set up a consistent dev environment with something like [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) then you can keep your environment consistent whether or not it's in the office or at home. We use these kinds of environments at my office.

Comment: unfortunately i still have that error on gulp command under my app folder. i tried those commands and --save command too. but no luck !

Comment: Also looking at your Gulp file and your console output your Sass task seems to be starting and completing just fine. But you're doing the same thing twice in your gulp file. You have two 'default' functions and then you're calling `gulp.watch("css/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('css/partials/*.scss', ['sass']);` once in your serve function and then again in the default. Perhaps the sequencing is causing your issue.